# cannot set post_max_size in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, configuration, laravel-4, wamp

Details :-  Stack : WAMP 
 OS : Windows 7.
I am using Laravel 4 and I know by using `ini_set('post_max_size','40M');` we can manually set the php.ini `post_max_size` value.
The index.php file inside laravel's public/ folder runs the first time the project is opened so I wrote `ini_set('post_max_size','40M');` inside that `public/index.php` file and started the app once again but when i tried to see the value of post_max_size by using `echo ini_get('post_max_size');` it shows 3M that is by default in the php.ini file .

Does laravel has some limitation while setting the php.ini values manually or am i doing something wrong ? 
I want to set that value by programmatically, NOT by going inside the php.ini and changing the value there. 
Note: I also tried writing the code inside a helper file and called that file in autoload but that also didn't worked this means `ini_set('post_max_size','40M');` is not at all working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a value you can not set programatcally.  You can see a table of all the variables in php.ini and when you can and can't change them here...

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php and http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

"Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)"

If you have access to your htaccess file, instead you can do...

```
php_value  post_max_size 40M
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that info.So do u know how to set it in `.htaccess` ?because in my hosting service i cant find any `php.ini` file or the others mentioned .Can just edit the `.htaccess `

Comment: Yes it worked in my localhost. Have to try in my hosting service .But anyways your answer is correct.