# Change php.ini setting in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

HI I want to change some of php.ini setting like `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` I ran php.info() and found the correct php.ini file I changed it and reset the wamp then I ran php.info() again and I saw that the setting wasn't applied ,so how can I change php.ini setting in laravel?
P.S: I wanted to upload a large file in laravel and I ran in to this problem

Comment: can u tell us you want to increase it via your server or via laravel framework ?

Comment: check your apache's php.ini file and change there.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after the change?

Comment: **PLEASE** tell me your reason for downvotes!!!!

Comment: @Mit.agile I want to do it via laravel framework

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes I did

Comment: @MohammadReza would you mind doing it using **.htaccess** ?

Comment: @Mit.agile how can I do it and where is it? (sorry for being too noob)

Comment: check this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250527/cannot-set-post-max-size-in-laravel-4 not sure which laravel version you are using.

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 mistakes people make when amending the `php.ini` file in WAMPServer

#### Updating the wrong file.

See [this post for a correct method of editing the right file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24263601/2310830)

#### Editing the wrong piece of the `php.ini` file

At the top of the file are a lot of comments intended to help people understand what most of the parameters do. Do not edit these comments. Instead search again for the parameter you want to change it should appear again later in the file.

```
post_max_size = 8M
```

Is on line 660 (or there abouts depending on version)

```
upload_max_filesize = "16M"
```

Is on line  810 (or there abouts depending on version)

> Final Note: Remember that the `post_max_size` must be > that the `upload_max_filesize` because the uploaded files are part of the POST payload but you need to include space in the `post_max_size` for the other fields on a form as well as the file(s)

### Additional checks

If the above is not the issue then :-

Do you have a php.ini in the wrong place. Check your boot drive for any other php.ini file. There shoud be no `php.ini` files outside the `\wamp\` folder. There is lots af bad advice out there and some suggest to put the php.ini file in the `\windows` or `\windows\system32` folders. If you find any other delete them.

There is also bad advice out there suggesting that you add the PHP folder to your system PATH. If you have anything to do with WAMPServer on your PATH remove it.

Comment: I change the right php.ini but it didn't applied to phpinfo();

Comment: See additional suggestions